# Programmatically retrieving the selected object of an NSArrayController

Tags: cocoa, nsarraycontroller

When I use an `NSArrayController` with instances of `NSManagedObject`, I was under the impression that the following would give me its selected object:

```
[myArrayController selection]
```

However, this gives me an instance of some private NS Proxy class.

When I use:

```
[[myArrayController selectedObjects] objectAt: 0]
```

...all is fine and I have my instance of `NSManagedObject`.

I understand the necessity for these methods as you can probably have lists which allow for multiple selection. I do not understand why `selection` does not give me the instance of `NSManagedObject`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It states in the documentation for NSObjectController (which NSArrayController inherits from) that this method returns a proxy object.

You will be able to use any KVC methods on the proxy object, but if you want any class - specific functionality you will have to use the second method in your sample above. As you've stated, this is to return a valid object in cases of no or multiple selection.

Comment: Actually, you can also bypass the proxy by getting its `self` value: `[[myArrayController selection] valueForKey:@"self"]`. Note that you have to use KVC to do this, calling the `self` method will return the proxy.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw This was a huge mystery and headache for me... With that out of the way, I immediately become curious about your username.